# 'Expanding' contents of Dataframe column into new columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm sure there must be away to do this without resorting to nested loops.

I have a df (note there is a column with lists of strings)

```
df = DataFrame({'A' : [5,6,3,4], 'B' : [1,2,3,5], 'C' : [['a','b'],['b','c'] ,['g','h'],['x','y']]})
```

ultimately I want to 'expand' out the values in the lists in the column so that there is a col for each possible list item, and for each row there is a 1 in the correct column if that value appears. e.g.

```
df =

A  B      C      a  b  c  g  h  x  y
5  1  ['a','b']  1  1
6  2  ['b','c']     1  1
3  3  ['g','h']           1  1
4  5  ['x','y']                 1  1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pandas.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html), but then need `groupby` by `columns` and aggregate `max`:

```
df1 = pd.get_dummies(pd.DataFrame(df.C.values.tolist()), prefix='', prefix_sep='')
        .groupby(axis=1, level=0).max()

df1 = pd.concat([df, df1], axis=1)
print (df1)

   A  B       C  a  b  c  g  h  x  y
0  5  1  [a, b]  1  1  0  0  0  0  0
1  6  2  [b, c]  0  1  1  0  0  0  0
2  3  3  [g, h]  0  0  0  1  1  0  0
3  4  5  [x, y]  0  0  0  0  0  1  1
```

Another solution with [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) + [`str.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html):

```
df1 = df.C.astype(str).replace(['\[','\]', "'", "\s+"], '', regex=True).str.get_dummies(',')
df1 = pd.concat([df, df1], axis=1)
print (df1)

   A  B       C  a  b  c  g  h  x  y
0  5  1  [a, b]  1  1  0  0  0  0  0
1  6  2  [b, c]  0  1  1  0  0  0  0
2  3  3  [g, h]  0  0  0  1  1  0  0
3  4  5  [x, y]  0  0  0  0  0  1  1
```

Also is possible remove `0`, but get strings values with numeric and some pandas function can be broken:

```
df1 = df.C.astype(str).replace(['\[','\]', "'", "\s+"], '', regex=True).str.get_dummies(',')
df1 = df1.replace(0,'')
df1 = pd.concat([df, df1], axis=1)
print (df1)
   A  B       C  a  b  c  g  h  x  y
0  5  1  [a, b]  1  1               
1  6  2  [b, c]     1  1            
2  3  3  [g, h]           1  1      
3  4  5  [x, y]                 1  1
```

Comment: that's great! it works. but is there anyway to do it 'inplace'. The dataframe I'm trying to manipulate is ~20GB

Comment: `get_dummies` is complicated function, so unfortuntely I cannot help you. `20GB` is really large df :(

Comment: thanks though. Yeah, too big. i might try breaking it down and doing it piece meal. Or just get cleverer at using the data in it's current structure.